# Ejecutar función en keypress al 3 caracter insertado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estimados par no hacer largo los post, ya se solucione el tema del keypress en otro post, lo que necesito ahora es que la función del keypress se ejecute cuando inserten 3 caracteres en el input dejo el código con la función como quedo, creo que puedo usar lenght y luego ejecutar la función tengo la idea pero no me sale, puden darme una mano gracias.

```js
function Cargardata () {
 var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

    $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

        $.each(data.data, function(key, item) {
            if ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
                output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
                output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('content').html(output);
    });

}

$('#btnSearch').click(function() {
    Cargardata();
});

$('#search').keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        Cargardata();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que #serch es tu input text debería funcionar si lo haces justo como dices, comparando su longitud

```js
function Cargardata () {
 var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

    $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

        $.each(data.data, function(key, item) {
            if ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
                output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
                output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('content').html(output);
    });

}

$('#btnSearch').click(function() {
    Cargardata();
});

$('#search').keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        if($(this).val().length > 3){
$("#elSpan").text("");
        Cargardata();
        return false;
       } else {
        //Aquí le pones el mensaje al <span> 
$("#elSpan").text("Ingrese mínimo tres caracteres");
}
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola User, tu codigo tiene errores y no permite ser probado. Puedes arreglarlo? Recuerda añadir una explicacion de cómo funciona el codigo. Un saludo

Comment: tu código funciono lo hace tal cual pero quiero enviar un alert cuando no cumple la condición de 3 caracteres como le agrego el alert mas abajo hice la modificación pero no salio ayuda por favor.

Comment: Mmmm no te lo recomendaría. El código ese se ejecuta cada vez que presionas una tecla, por lo tanto MINIMO te van a salir un par de alertas antes de que sea válido. Y eso está muy mal, pues sería super enfadoso para el usuario escribir la primera letra y que salga un alert, escribir la segunda y que salga otro alert... Sí me doy a entender?

Comment: como le indicaría al usuario que tiene que poner los 3 caracteres mínimo? esta funcionando pero no sabe, que tiene que poner 3 caracteres para que salgan resultados.

Comment: Puedes poner un placeholder en el input que le indique que debe teclear mínimo tres caracteres para la búsqueda

Comment: O puedes poner un mensjae abajo del input ese que le diga que mínimo tres. Actualicé mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Pues solo consulta el tamaño de tu cadena, podrías agregar el evento **keyup** para entenderlo mejor

```js
$('#search').keyup(function(e) {
  if($(this).val().length>3){
    alert("mas de 3");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search">
```

Comment: creo que deberia ser `>2` la comprobacion si quiere que el mensaje sea al introducir el 3er caracter, basada en el titulo de la pregunta "al tercer caracter insertado" (no al cuarto)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando el evento keypress quedaria asi

```
 $('#search').keypress(function(e){
 var length = $(this).val().length;
  if(length >= 2){
    console.log('Do stuff')
  }
});
```

puesto que el evento keypress hace la comprobacion con el movimiento de down y up del teclado completo, por eso la comprobacion va con el valor 2, para una implementación diferente puedes probar con keydown https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: Hola Oscar, bienvenido a [es.so]. Esta respuesta es casi igual a la ya anteriormente respondida por parte de Shassain..él usa un `keyup` y tu un `keypress`... Intenta editarla para que sea algo distinto o y asi no tener publicaciones repetidas. Y considera usar snippets de codigo para que el autor pueda probar tu solucion. Un saludo